# thinking problem geometry

Tags: arithmetic

i need different views on this question. How would you solve it? If all iPhones were stacked, would they be taller than the tallest mountain on Earth?

Comment: there should be around $10^8$ Iphones on the world, wich are each around $1 cm $ thick which means that when stacked they are around $1000 km$ high. Since the highest mountain on earth is around $8.8 km$ high, the stacked IPhones are much much taller (even if my approximations are not super thight)

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/how-many-iphones-have-been-sold-1999500

so $10000km$ seem to be a better approximation (that is neary a quarter of earth cirumference!)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely approach this by visiting this website [iPhone](http://www.apple.com/contact/)

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd ask Apple for the number of iPhones that have been sold for each model, getting the numbers $n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_6$ (are we at iPhone 6?).
2. I'd look for the dimension in $\mathrm{cm}$ of each iPhone (does "stacked" mean that you want to add them by width?), getting the numbers $w_1,\cdots,w_6$
3. I'd look for the height $h$ in $\mathrm{cm}$ of mount Everest
4. I'd check with a calculator (I could do with pen and paper, but I can't be bothered) if $\sum_{k=1}^6 w_kn_k$ is greater than $h$.